# how does my org mode have different fonts in src block / table and other texts?

Tags: org-mode, fonts

I am surprised to find the font used in table / src block is different from normal text (see below). Any one knows why? and how to make the font universal?

The "0" on heading:
[image]
The "0" in src block:
[image]
The "0" in table:
[image]

I have not set up font in my customization except one line:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `org-table` face and `org-block` face inherit from `fixed-pitch` so you can set the font for that face with

```el
(set-face-attribute 'fixed-pitch nil :font "Sarasa Mono SC Nerd-12")
```

Most faces inherit from `default` but not these two.

Comment: The reason that `org-table` inherits from `fixed-pitch` is of course table alignment: the simple algorithm that's used by Org mode cannot deal with variable-width fonts. It's not as clear to me why `org-block` does so as well, possibly because that's what a code block "should look like": indentation matters but as long as there are reasonable tab stops for that, I don't think a variable-width font would be too much of a problem.